# How to customize pageSize in RESTier?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, paging, restier

In RESTier documentation, it is written that we can manage the maxTop number of results like this :
config.Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().MaxTop(50).Count();
It works well if the client uses the $top keyword explicitly.
However, the client can still access the rest resource with a simple request "www.rest.com/api/users" and get the whole table.
Does a server result limit configuration exist, to prevent slowdown? (Like the WebApi paging feature)

Answer (score 0):

**PageSize**
Gets or sets the maximum number of query results to send back to clients.

Comment: It's exactly what I want to use, but how ? It seems that it is not available in Restier, just in WebAPI.  I see no trace of it in the documentation http://odata.github.io/RESTier/ , and the PageSize annotation on my model is not working.  There is a ticket about this issue on github (https://github.com/OData/RESTier/issues/52), however I though there might be an alternative configuration method.

Comment: On your Model
[Page(MaxTop = 5, PageSize = 1)]
[See](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-01-modelbound-attribute)
Page Attribute

Comment: It does not work in my test project. The annotation has no effect. Your link refers to WebAPI documentation

Comment: If you read the section you will see its Web API OData. RESTier is built on top of Web API OData. The Page Attribute is a new feature since Web API OData 6. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 6. The page size is working on relations, but it doesn't work on entities.

Comment: How about an [Entity Set Filter](http://odata.github.io/RESTier) you could add top(whatever) but you don't get a next page link

Comment: I tried with a basic Entity Set Filter (entitySet.Take<Credential>(10).AsQueryable()), but it gives an exception when $top is specified in the request.
The only solution I see is to implement IQueryExpressionProcessor interface, but it seems complex.
The question has been asked here : https://github.com/OData/RESTier/issues/501